# How can I center the equation in the "description" environment

Tags: beamer

I am a new LaTeX user.

When I tried to use the "description" environment in the Beamer, I found that the equations under each item are not centered on the page. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you[image]

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\title{Geometry}
\newcommand{\diff}{\,\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Fundamentals}
\begin{description}
    \item[Spherical to Cartesian Coordinates]
    \begin{align}
        x &= \sin\theta \cos\phi\\
        y &= \sin\theta \sin\phi\\
        z &= \cos\theta
    \end{align}
    
    \item[Differential Solid Angle]
    \begin{equation}
        \diff \Omega = \sin\theta \diff\theta \diff\phi
    \end{equation}
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same trick as `amsart`.

```latex
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\everydisplay=\expandafter{\expandafter\fullwidthdisplay\the\everydisplay}
\newcommand{\fullwidthdisplay}{\displayindent=0pt \displaywidth=\columnwidth}

\title{Geometry}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Fundamentals}
\[
        \diff \Omega = \sin\theta \diff\theta \diff\phi
\]
\begin{description}
    \item[Spherical to Cartesian Coordinates]
    \begin{align}
        x &= \sin\theta \cos\phi\\
        y &= \sin\theta \sin\phi\\
        z &= \cos\theta
    \end{align}
    
    \item[Differential Solid Angle]
    \begin{equation}
        \diff \Omega = \sin\theta \diff\theta \diff\phi
    \end{equation}
\end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I added the first equation to better show the centering.

I also modified your `\diff` command to only add a thin space when necessary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, your suggestion works well!